# How to add -fpermissive option while installing qt 4.6.2

Tags: qt

I am facing a problem with qt installation. I have GCC 4.7.2 and I am trying to install qt 4.6.2. I noticed that 'make' throws an error while compiling some files under /src/3rdparty folder. I can solve that problem by setting -fermissive flag somewhere. But I am not sure where. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

You could use this:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -permissive
```

See the  documentation for details:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/qmake-variable-reference.html#qmake-cxxflags

If you would not like to change any project file, you could set it on the command line while invoking qmake the following way:

```
qmake -set VARIABLE VALUE
```